# Can't get button to change color based on information in the next page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the background color of the button to change based on if a sessionStorage item is marked true. On the next page, the Kitchen page, when all the buttons are checked, the sessionStorage item becomes true so when you go back to the "home page",the kitchen is now marked green instead of red. This is the show completion. I think you can use jQuery but I don't really know how to use it.

Home

```
function loader(){
        var form = document.getElementById("myForm");

        //error somewhere in here
        for(var i=0;i<form.length;i++){
            if(sessionStorage.getItem(form.elements[i].value) == "true"){
                document.getElementById(form.elements[i].value).style.backgroundColor = "green";
                return true;
            }else{
                document.getElementById(form.elements[i].value).style.backgroundColor = "red";
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    function initial(){
        if (localStorage.getItem("hasCodeRunBefore") === null) {
                var form = document.forms[0];
                var tot = document.forms[0].length;
                var i;
                for(var i = 0; i < tot ; ++i){
            document.getElementById(form.elements[i].value).style.backgroundColor = "red";
                }
            localStorage.setItem("hasCodeRunBefore", true);
        }
    }

    function start(){
        initial();
        loader();
    }
```

Home HTML

```
<body onload="start()">
<header align=center>Home Screen</header>
<p align=center id="result"></p>
<script>
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("currentAddress");
</script>

<ul align=center>
    <form id="myForm">
        <li>        
                <input type="button" name="area" id="livingroom" value="Living Room" ><br><br>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                        sessionStorage.setItem("livingroom","false");
                        document.getElementById("livingroom").onclick = function () {
                        location.href = "url";
                    };
                </script>
        </li>
        <li>        
                <input type="button" name="area" id="kitchen" value="Kitchen"><br><br>  
                <script type="text/javascript">
                        sessionStorage.setItem("kitchen","false");
                        document.getElementById("kitchen").onclick = function () {
                        location.href = "url";
                    };
                </script>
        </li>
        <li>
                <input type="button" name="area" id="bathroom" value="Bathroom" ><br><br>   
                <script type="text/javascript">
                        sessionStorage.setItem("bathroom","false");
                        document.getElementById("bathroom").onclick = function () {
                        location.href = "url";
                    };
                </script>
        </li>
        <li>        
                <input type="button" name="area" id="dining" value="Dining" ><br><br>   
                <script type="text/javascript">
                        sessionStorage.setItem("dining","false");
                        document.getElementById("dining").onclick = function () {
                        location.href = "url";
                    };
                </script>
        </li>
        <li>        
                <input type="button" name="area" id="bedroom1" value="Bedroom 1" ><br><br>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                        sessionStorage.setItem("bedroom1","false");
                        document.getElementById("bedroom1").onclick = function () {
                        location.href = "url";
                    };
                </script>       
        </li>
    </form>
</ul>
```

Kitchen

```
function checkTasks(form){
        var count = 0;
        for(var i=0;i<form.task.length;i++){
            if(form.task[i].checked){
                count++;
            }
        }

        if(count == form.task.length){
            sessionStorage.setItem("kitchen","true");
            window.open("url");
        }else{
            alert("You have not completed all the tasks! Please check all the boxes to indicate you have completed the tasks. If there is an issue, write it in the other box.");
        }
    }
```

Kitchen HTML

```
<body>
<header align=center>Kitchen To Do List</header>
<form name="todolist" >
    <div id="button">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="task" value="1" ><p>Microwave</p>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div id="button">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="task" value="1"><p>Coffee Maker</p>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div id="button">   
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="task" value="1"><p>Oven</p>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div id="button">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="task" value="1"><p>Dishwasher</p>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div id="button">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="task" value="1"><p>Stove Top</p>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div id="button">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="task" value="1"><p>Other</p>
        </label>
    </div>

    <textarea id="other"></textarea><br><br>
    <p align=center>
        <input type="submit" name="box" id="box" value="Complete" onclick="checkTasks(this.form)">
    </p>
</form>

<div class="close">
    <form align=center action="url" target="_self">
        <input type="submit" name="back" value="Back">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML also, because the issue could lie with the ID's

Comment: Sure! thanks for the advice. Let me know if I need to add anything else. As a sidenote:the url targets as the their respective pages home->kitchen kitchen->home.

Comment: There it is! Thanks for providing the HTML. Like I said, it might be an issue with the ID's, and it is. You are using `document.getElementById()` and yet none of your elements have ID's, therefore, no background colours will change.

Comment: Ok, I'm a bit confused. So my elements in home have ids based on if they are a part of kitchen, living, etc. Where should I be adding ids?

Comment: My bad, I wrote that incorrectly. I meant to say that the values are different to the ID's and therefore, using `form[i].value` wont grab the correct element. For instance, the value `Living Room` will not work with the ID `livingroom`

Comment: Oh, I noticed that was an issue. Do you have any idea on how to get the id of an element in a form?

Comment: `document.getElementById()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you load the home page you are setting the value to false with those inline scripts. Remove the `sessionStorage.setItem("livingroom","false");` calls in home.html and it looks like everything will work.

Comment: Ok so I tried this but didn't seem to work. I did alittle testing and after I noticed the loader function isn't loading the for loop I have in place. Do you think it is rooted there or am I missing something else? Sorry about the delayed response

Comment: Nevermind, your method worked! Thanks so much. One more thing to note, I'm not sure how to get the id of an element in a form which is the last thing I need.

Comment: Just like I'm your loop where you access the value but instead of `.value` it's `.id`